# Power BI - I need a "countif" formula to look at unique entries in row/column

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, countif

I have only been working in Power BI for a little over one week now, and now I have run into my first problem..

I need a way to do the same as in below Excel formula..

In Power Bi I have ONE table.
I want to count unique "Split Orders" in column "B"

But I only want to count them once..
So the first time it is found, it is counted as 1
Next I see it it is counted as 2 or 3 or 4 or more..

So formula says "if counted MORE than once, then return "X", else return "1"
And the IF statement then says if higher than 1, return 0 else return 1

I have many thousands of rows and I need to identify each as either unique or not..
But I can't seem to find the right combo of DAX formulas to do so.
I have looked at `COUNTDISTINCT, CALCULATE, FILTERS, COUNTROWS`, and many more.
They might be the right ones to use but I haven’t managed to find the right syntax.

Many of the DAX formulas I have tried, either return ONLY "1" or ONLY "0" or they return the total amount of unique orders..

Excel formula:

```
Row 2 = IF(B2="";0;IF(COUNTIF(B$1:$B2;B2)>1;0;1))
Row22 = IF(B22="";0;IF(COUNTIF(B$1:$B22;B22)>1;0;1))
Row32 = IF(B32="";0;IF(COUNTIF(B$1:$B32;B32)>1;0;1))
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide us with some sample data and expected result based on that data.

Comment: Why is the measure  `DistinctCount Split Orders = DISTINCTCOUNT('table'[Split Orders])` not working for you?

Comment: Unique Split Order    / Split Order
1 685286-0
1 686866-0
1 686868-0
1 686879-0
1 686880-0
1 689059-0
1 689059-1
1 689066-0
1 689066-1
1 689070-0
1 689070-1
1 689083-0
1 689083-1
1 689084-0
0 689084-0
1 689084-1
1 689084-2
1 689087-0
1 689094-0
1 689395-0
0 689395-0
1 689396-0
1 689396-1
1 689397-0
1 689398-0
1 689402-0
0 689402-0
1 689404-0

I need the measure or DAX formula to return either 0 or 1.. Where 1 means the order number is unique, and 0 for orders that appear MORE than once in the list. I don't need the total amount, I need it per row.

Comment: The different variations I have tried all return EITHER only zeros OR only one.. OR count of total unique

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Calculated  Column and not a Measure. Also you need to determine the order in which the [Split Order] column should be read.

You can do this by adding an index column in Power Query (Add Column tab). After doing that, add this Calculated Column:

```
IsFirstOccurence =
IF (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            'table',
            'table'[Split Order] = EARLIER ( 'table'[Split Order] )
                && 'table'[Index] <= EARLIER ( 'table'[Index] )
        )
    ) = 1,
    1,
    0
)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco... Almost what I need... I see that in your example both 2 & 3 are counted as "0"... But first time I see 2 then it should be a "1" but the next time I see 2 it should be "0".. Same for 3... First time I see 3 it should be a "1", and next times I see 3 it should be "0"...   ALL of the split orders should be counted as "1" the first time it is seen, all other instances should be "0"..

Comment: How do you determin the order in your table? Is there a date column or an index column?

Comment: Something like a "CountDistinctRows" or similar

Comment: There are many columns with dates .. Also a column formatted as "yyyy-mm".. Don't know if such row can be used..